# Question : the correlation between the width of the data bus in DRAM and the data type

Tags: memory, arm, ram

Let's assume a 64-bit ARM system with a 64-bit data bus, and the DRAM can transfer 64 bits of data to the data bus every clock cycle.

Now, let's consider a scenario where we create an environment with restricted cache usage using the **volatile** keyword.

In such a scenario, one might expect that the performance should be the same when transferring N data elements of int64_t and int32_t from DRAM to the CPU.

However, experimental results show that the speed of transferring 100 million int64_t data elements and 100 million int32_t data elements is not the same.

```
Time to read 100 million int64_t data elements = 7.04 ms.
Time to read 100 million int32_t data elements = 4.09 ms.
```

I am curious why the performance is not the same in a situation where the cache is not involved. Is there something I might have missed?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is related to your other question.   A 64 bit arm system likely has memory down and not dimms.  If you are talking phone for example it is likely a 16 bit wide dram bus.  Absolutely not able to do one per clock. (nor two since it is DDR).  At least not sustained.  Otherwise why have a cache at all???

volatile has nothing to do with cache usage it a high level language thing that has to do with the construction of the code (generally it creates more code, more instructions, takes longer to execute).

volatile does not disable the cache. Cached or not has to do with the mmu settings for that address space and other factors.

You have not remotely provided enough information.  Are you running on an operating system, are you running at the application layer, etc etc.   Please provide a complete minimal example.  Are you reading linearly through memory or remaining in a cache line?  Is this a commercially available arm based board you are running on that you can name for reference or a closed design?

From a prior question of yours, this likely has one dram chip, likely a 16 bit wide bus, yet DDR so 32 bits per clock (for the bursts where it is able to do a transaction).  And the bytes, say a burst of 8 are going to be linear in that memory, you may still have some leveling across the system that makes your view of linear address space striped in the dram.

But so far nothing about this question has to do with dram.